# Trying to use vm.$apply(), but it throws an error “vm.$apply is not a function”

Tags: angularjs

I'm working in a SPA with Angular JS. I have a problem with `$apply()` in

```
var vm = this;
vm.$apply(function(){};);
```

> error : vm.$apply is not a function

Should I use `$scope` instead? Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

there is no property `$apply` on vm. vm is just reference to this controller function while `$apply` is only available on special scope objects
e.g. $scope.$apply or $rootScope.$apply,

use

```
$scope.$apply()
```

and inject this dependency

Comment: Thank you for your response :)